# Query Builder summarize the field value depending on another field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have some table
[image: my some table]

I need select an group iformation from these, but a have some conditions:

- Group results by date (day). Ideally when day start on 09.00 and finsh 09.00 (24hr)
- Then i need summarize values field `sum` where `'satus_id'` = 10 into new variable example `'TotalIn'` and where `status_id` = 12 into variable example `TotalOut`
- Give results on view (but this no problem)

How to do it?
I write this, but i now this is wrong:

```
$statistic =   DB::connection('mysql2')->table('payout_transactions')
        ->selectRaw('*, DATE(date) as day')
        ->where('status_id', 12)
        ->selectRaw('SUM(sum) AS TotalIn')
        ->groupBy('day')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could consider is:

```
DB::table('market')
->selectRaw('SUM(sum) as total, status_id, DATE("date") as day')
->whereIn('status_id', [10,12])
->groupBy([DB::raw(DATE('date')), 'status_id'])
->get()
```

That should give the sums for day, separately for both status_ids (10 or 12).

Comment: This is good, but i need get SUM separately 10 and 12. Example `totalIn` this is sum all values in group where `status_id` = 10. and `totalOut` all walues in group where `status_id` = 12

Comment: It is separately, because each row contains sumed value (aliased total), status_id (either 10 or 12) and the day.

Comment: so when iterating through the collection you could do if ($item->status_id == 10) // it is TOTAL IN else // it is TOTAL OUT